# TeX4ht: broken hyperlinks when using internal counters for `\newtheorem`

Tags: counters, tex4ht, amsthm

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

We see Lemma~\ref{lem:test}

\begin{lemma}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    i^2=-1
  \end{equation}
  in $\mathbb C$.
  \label{lem:test}
\end{lemma}

Lemma~\ref{lem:test}

\end{document}
```

Then `tex4ebook` will generate incorrect hyperlinks:

`We see Lemma <a href="#x1-2r2">1<!--tex4ht:ref: lem:test --></a>`

`<span class="head"><a id="x1-2r1"></a><span class="ecbx-1000">Lemma 1.</span>  </span>`

I wonder whether this overriding `equation` counter is deprecated for `tex4ht` (or general `LaTeX` programming), or it is due to a bug?

Comment: Try putting the `\label` immediately after the `\lemma` line.  `\ref` by default refers to the most recent element with a referrable number -- and that's the `equation`,

Comment: The solution advised by Barbara seems to work

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks a lot. In fact, `\ref` gets the correct number, but after having enabled `hyperref`, I find that the hyperlink is wrong (it will be more obvious after placing a `\newpage` before `\begin{lemma}`: it will go to another page), even compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: What happens if you use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I cannot spot any change from `\newpage` to `\clearpage` for `pdflatex`. Still `Lemma 1` but if I click it, it will redirect me to the equation on the page 2.

Comment: You did run pdflatex twice after changing to `\clearpage`?  I have copied the example file, inserted `\clearpage`, and moved the label to follow the `\lemma` line.  When I run pdflatex twice and test the link, it connects to the page with the lemma.  So I can't reproduce the problem with the information given.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I was not totally clear. I mean, I do **not** move the label. I already knew that moving the label would work. The previous comment was trying to explain that my observation does not completely coincide with what you said: In my example, the number generated by `\ref` is still the number of the lemma, not "by default refers to the most recent element with a referrable number -- and that's the equation", but the hyperlink is directed to the equation.

Comment: When the label is attached to the equation -- as it is, because the equation is numbered -- it can't possibly link to the lemma.  It would link to the lemma if you use `equation*` (not numbered), but you're asking for something impossible as long as the equation has a number.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It seems to me that I have not explained well. You said that in my example, the label `lem:test` is attached to the equation. You are explaining that `\ref{lem:test}` will link to the equation in my case. Given that this is true, but I am asking why `\ref{lem:test}` is rendered as `1`, the number of the lemma, instead of `2`, the number of the equation, given that the label `lem:test` is attached to the equation in my example? That is to say, why doesn't the numbering system coincide with the link system? It is just out of curiosity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108794/discussion-between-barbara-beeton-and-yai0phah).